# Javascript PHP N-Tier Architecture

Tags: php, javascript, html, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I'm confused how to classify the project I'm doing if it is 3-tier or 2-tier.

Basically it's a medical service system and it's using PHP and JS(with Jquery and Ajax); both are used for the business logic. I've been told by someone more knowledgeable that it's 3-tier; I'm not sure why...perhaps because HTML is thought of as the presentation layer, PHP and more importantly, JS, as the business layer, while PHP (with MySQL) are for the data access layer? Is that it? Personally, I think it's 2-tier. Can someone please enlighten me with a detailed explanation for this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why does it matter? Also, the terms aren't especially well-defined, so why don't you just make up/apply your own definition? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-tier_architecture

Comment: Well you are presenting the data, you have business logic to manipulate the data, and you have a data layer?

Comment: It matters because the architecture is part of the project defense. I've done my homework but I'm still torn between the two. Yes, the data is presented (through HTML and JS), business logic (JS and PHP), and PHP for data layer. But the layers are so connected to one another that it seems to be just 2-tier - that is, a client and server layer. How should I best put it exactly? So confusing

Comment: Too connected that the business logic (processed by PHP and JS), would be translated to presented by that same script (but maybe on a different method or function). Can that still be considered two different layers (business and presentation)?

Comment: wouldnt php hold the business logic? in the event that js would be disabled in the browser then there would still be php as a backup or the de facto business logic layer ?

Comment: In some cases it does; a combination of both actually. But the system relies on the use of JS for graphics in medical charting (e.g. what areas for highlighting to combine when something is selected given a procedure). I know it's backward thinking...but only 2-3% doesn't have JS anyway. And the system will just be used by specific clients.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definition agreed. I think of it as 2-tier client-server. Some will argue i guess...

Comment: Thanks. What layers are they exactly? Client and server layer?

Answer (score 1):

I thought that tiers referred to physical computers, not software layers. So a 3 tier architecture might be

1 - database server - mysql or some other database software

2 - application (web) server, running php or some other server side language

3 - clients (web browsers interpreting HTML and Javascript)

In a two tier architecture both database and application server are the same.

Comment: Wouldn't that make all browser-based systems all 3-tier? (1) MySQL for database, with (2) PHP needed to access it, and (3) for client's JS and HTML?

Comment: It would make them all two tier if MySQL and Apache/PHP were on the same server and three tier if MySQL was on a separate server.

Comment: It looks like there is a lot of confusion out there on the web about whether tiers refers to hardware or software. For example, this article talks about software layers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685068(v=vs.85).aspx (which may or may not be spread across more than one server) while this one talks about hardware servers http://www.codingthearchitecture.com/2012/07/20/when_do_you_need_a_3_tier_architecture.html

Comment: Very true. I'll just not mention n-tier in the project documentation. I just thought I'd ask it here to see what people has to say; because like what you mentioned, there's a lot of confusion out there regarding this topic. Probably because "there is no definition agreed" (acc. Maxim). upvoted also

Comment: I recall that once we wrote 3 rier app when all the database requests were called by stored procedure only. That was a strict rule and a lot of programming was done in PL/SQL under Oracle. Then PHP was rendering the data in XML, then our web interface interface was html/javascript and another team again was working on an app in java to be distributed on CDs. That case would make sense to call it 3 tier because, i suppose the whole logic was programmed on 3 different areas with intependent teams.